# couldn't get into function that 'this' is passed to it

Tags: parsing, reactjs

I am using setState() in a function in my code. I am passing object to that function. The problem is that the code does not get into the function`updateState` at all. In my code, please search for the `alert("got into the function")` and try to understand why the compiler cannot reach to that alert code line.

thanks

```js
var React = require('react');
var Parse = require('parse').Parse;
var ParseReact = require('parse-react');


module.exports = React.createClass({
mixins: [ParseReact.Mixin],

//Observe Function - a newly proposed function for prarse react integration
observe: function() {
  //declare any variable you need here.
  return {
    product: (new Parse.Query('product'))
              .ascending('createdAt')
  };
},

getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    // if the cookie is there, It will return the cookie value which I saved as 'true' word.
    FTWVeyCc4o : false,

  };
},

  //Render
  render: function() {

  

    if(this.data.product.length){

      var content = (
        <div >
          {this.data.product.map(function(p) {
            this.updateState.bind(this,p);

              return (
             

                //From Design
                <div className="col-md-4">

                    <div className="item text-center">

                        <div className="photo">

                            <img src={  p.productImgUrl }  />
                            <br /><br />
                            <h5>{p.name} <br /> {p.size}</h5>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                        <div className="action">
                            <button
                              type="button"
                              className={"btn btn-"
                                + (
                                      (this.state.FTWVeyCc4o && (p.objectId == "FTWVeyCc4o")) || (this.state.aJ3DoJp352 && (p.objectId == "aJ3DoJp352")) || (this.state.dgeRhSG21U && (p.objectId == "dgeRhSG21U")) ? 'warning' : 'primary'
                                  )}

                              onClick={this.ProductButtonClicked.bind(this, p)}
                              >
                              {(
                                (this.state.FTWVeyCc4o && (p.objectId == "FTWVeyCc4o")) || (this.state.aJ3DoJp352 && (p.objectId == "aJ3DoJp352")) || (this.state.dgeRhSG21U && (p.objectId == "dgeRhSG21U")) ? 'Remove' : 'Add'
                              )}
                            </button>
                        </div>


                </div>
              );
          }, this)}
        </div>

      );

    }
    else{
      var content = (<div>

      </div>)
      }
    return content;
  },

 

  //update state
  updateState:function(s){
alert("got into the function")
    if(s.objectId == "FTWVeyCc4o")
      {
     this.setState({FTWVeyCc4o: this.getCookiefunc('RahlTradingProductID-FTWVeyCc4o') });
      }
    
  },

  ProductButtonClicked:function(obj){
    if( this.getCookiefunc('RahlTradingProductID-' + obj.objectId) == ""  )
      {//alert("Create Cookie")
        //create the cookie
        document.cookie="RahlTradingProductID-" + obj.objectId + "=true; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2017 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
          //update state
          if(obj.objectId == "FTWVeyCc4o")
            {
              this.setState({FTWVeyCc4o:true});
            }
          else if(obj.objectId == "aJ3DoJp352")
            {
              this.setState({aJ3DoJp352:true});
            }
          else if(obj.objectId == "dgeRhSG21U")
            {
              this.setState({dgeRhSG21U:true});
            }
      }
    else
      {//alert("Delete Cookie")
        //delete the cookie
        document.cookie="RahlTradingProductID-" + obj.objectId + "=; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2000 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";

        if(obj.objectId == "FTWVeyCc4o")
          {
            this.setState({FTWVeyCc4o:false});
          }
        else if(obj.objectId == "aJ3DoJp352")
          {
            this.setState({aJ3DoJp352:false});
          }
        else if(obj.objectId == "dgeRhSG21U")
          {
              this.setState({dgeRhSG21U:false});
          }

      }

    /

  getCookiefunc:function(cname){
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
  }

});
```

code is below:

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your function `updateState()` is never actually called from your code.

The `this.updateState.bind(this,p)` bind parameters to your function, but doesn't call it.

Your code needs to have:

- either a `this.updateState(p)` statement somewhere,
- or a `onClick = { this.updateState.bind(this,p)`}  inside your Jsx (buttons)

In the second case, your function gets called whenever user clicks a button.
Currently, button clicks calls `productButtonClicked`. But inside that function, you only call setState, and not updateState.

Comment: assume I need to call the updateState function inside the loop and not inside button click. for example, (this.data.product.map(function(p){ thisupdateState....); so how can I fix it this way?

Comment: Calling the function from inside the loop means changing the `...bind()` statement to `this.updateState(p)`. But this will not work: you should not call `setState()` inside a render loop. OK to call from `productButtonClicked`.

Comment: Still I need to call the updateState function from inside a loop, so how can I resolve that?

Comment: You should not set state inside a render cycle. You could move/copy the `this.data.product.map()` loop to somewhere outside the render cycle, maybe inside a react  `componentWillReceiveProps()` lifecycle function.

Comment: Since you are using Parse-react, the solution may be in including you cookie inside the `observe()` function. (I am not too familiar with parse).